# PHP Login/Authentication/Sessions/API/Token

Tags: php, authentication, token

I need to develop a very secure login system.

I have an API layer, and my plan is to create a token table. I'll send the username/password (Post) to my API and I generate a unique token (One time token with limited time), I return the token in JSON.

My questions are:

1. What should be saved in the sessions while user is logged in. I want to store as little as possible information. Should I save the token only? Is it safe?
2. I don't want to store the access levels and user info in session, then I need to get these info each time via token.. what do you think? Advice!
3. Any other advice to develop more secure login system.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you intend to use the token as a session_id?

Comment: I thought so,.. but what do you think? What is your opinion?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure but it looks not secure to me.

Comment: What would you store in the session?

Comment: I think the kind of data which is stored is not important from the point of view of security. The span of regenerating token is more important for security, I think.

Comment: @Na30m maybe my answer helped you too:P

Answer (score 2):

Since you'd like to keep sessions as logged in identification, you will probably encounter a problem: some clients can't be kept session.

For example, cell phones, web-based app.

I'm creating a similar project. And my solution is

1. Creating a table named `session` (or whatever you want), that keeps `UserToken` (randomly generated), `UserID`, `TokenExpire`.
2. Once the user logged in, create a record at `session` table, and return the token to the user (encoded into `JSON`).
3. User keeps the `token` their own, and attached the `token` on every request. (No matter body or header, I'm using header to separate from the data).
4. Check the `token` every time before they asking for something. For Example, Is the `token` exists? Is the `token` expired? Is the user be blocked?
5. By the step 4., you can also get what the user is by querying relatively.

That is my solution. It's similar to your way.

Additionally, To improve the security, follow the ways if could

1. Use `SSL` (HTTP) to secure the connection between server and clients.
2. Don't keep their `Password` plaintext. You should encrypt them.
3. You can generate the `token` as longer as possible.
4. The `token` field of `session` table, should be **Case Sensitive**. Change the collation different from `_ci` (means **Case Insensitive**)
5. Check the `POST` data to prevent `SQL Injection`. **Never trust what users give to you.**

The instructions above are fundamental. I always do that.

Comment: But if I want to use Session, what should I store in my session? Token? Or user email address for instance?

Comment: @Na30m Anything you want, except `Username`, `Password`. I store `Token` in session, too. If the session is provided, then use it. If not, read the `Token` user gave to you.

Answer (score 1):

this is just a small list on how you can handle it with sessions, cookies and of course a database and php:P **not with JSON**

you can use a database like this
[image: db_for_log_reg]

so the session should contain an array with an index of login, so you can later check if the session isset and restrict acces to a **user_only_page**. like this:

```
$_SESSION = array(
  "login" => true,
  "data" => array(
      "username" => $row["username"], // is not a must and not unsafe / you can let it out if you want
      "email" => $row["email"], // this is also not a must
      "time" => time()+60*10 // so here you can set a time how long the session is available. for this example it is 10min.
  )
);
```

set a cookie for a "remember_me" checkbox like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["remember_me"]) && $_POST["remember_me"] === "accepted") {
     $_SESSION = array(
           "login" => true,
           "data" => array(
              "username" => $row["username"], //not a must
              "email" => $row["email"], //also not a must
              "time" => time() +3600*24*30 //set the time higher, so that the user won't bee kicked out after 10min when he logged in.
             )
       );
    setcookie('remember_me', md5($emailUsername . time()), time() +3600*24*30);
}
```

then you can write a file, that is included in every page and handles all sessions or cookies. like this:

```
ob_start(); //Turns on the output buffering

if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) { //here we check if the session isset(true)

    if ($_SESSION["data"]["time"] >= time()) { //here we check if the session time we set before to 10min is greater than the actual time
        if(isset($_COOKIE["remember_me"])) { //if you want to let the user stayed in check if the cookie isset, and if redirect him directly to the userarea
            header('Location: ../path_to_theuserarea/userarea.php'); //the redirect
            exit();
        }
    }
    else { // here we go if the session time is lower than the actual time and kick the user out
        $_SESSION["login"] = false; //he has to  log_in again
        header('Location: ../path_to_the_login/login.php'); //redirect to the login.php
        exit();
    }
}
else { //here we check if the requested basename of a file is not login.php and if, redirect him to login.php. thats the part that will be included in your userarea.php
    if (basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) !== "login.php") {
        header('Location: ../path_to_the_login/login.php'); //redirect back to login
    }
}
ob_end_flush(); //end buffering
```

## also good for a secure login/register system are:

1. Account_Activation_Token: send a token after successful registered to the email that the user entered and only let him log in if he clicked on that link. I used this method for myself and also used `$_GET` for the activation token. Send a link like `https://YOUR_URL/log_reg/activateAccountWithToken.php?id=USERID&activation_token=RANDOMLY-STRING-WITH-50-CHARAKTERS`
2. you can also .htaccess to rewrite the url so that the URL is shown better. like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /log_reg/
    RewriteRule ^activate/([a-z]+)/?$   activationToken.php?id=$1   [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

after that you can use a url like `https://YOUR_URL/log_reg/activate/USERID/`

3. You can use a Cronjob for deleting all activation tokens from your db after some time, so that the user has to activate his account again.
4. NEVER store PLAINTEXT_PASSWORDS, use functions like password_hash() and password_verify()
5. use password_needs_rehash() function when the user loggs in so that the hash from the db will be regenerated everytime he loggs in.
6. force SSL with .htaccess and use **prepared-statements** for inserting the data to the database